# Issues With Cassandra Cluster ( 3.9 )

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

We running Cassandra cluster in following configuration :

3 Node cluster with factor replication of 3 and connecting from number of places, each node is Azure F4 Service with data disk ( 750GiB ) attached to it. Cassandra open source 3.9 everything is configured to "best" recommendations.

We have about 60 connections going to each node and we having tons of issues with the following error:

Applications using QUORUM for read and write

CassandraException: Write timeout: Operation timed out - received only 1 responses.

or

No hosts available: All hosts in current policy attempted and were either unavailable or failed

I find it hard to believe that 60 connections can kill Cassandra. CPU and memory on nodes never go above 60%

There is obviously bottleneck somewhere

What I am missing ?

Comment: The /var/log/system.log tells all. Other information such as data model, client connection code, nodetool status output can help us troubleshoot better.

Comment: well, we know all of that and still running into issues. I suspend may be 4 cores + 1 disk is not sufficient for each node.